# How to call a method from an inherit class

Tags: python, serial-port, jtag

I'm working on a project wich consist on testing a board connection with a JTAG connector and OpenOCD server.

Here is the connection class I've coded, it's simply using pexpect :

```
"""
Communication with embedded board
"""
import sys 
import time
import threading
import Queue

import pexpect
import serial
import fdpexpect

from pexpect import EOF, TIMEOUT


class ModTelnet():
    def __init__(self):    

        self.is_running = False
        self.HOST = 'localhost'
        self.port = '4444'

    def receive(self):
        #receive data (= msg) from telnet stdout
        data = [ EOF, TIMEOUT, '>' ]
        index = self._tn.expect(data, 2)
        if index == 0:
            return 'eof', None
        elif index == 1:
            return 'timeout', None
        elif index == 2:
            print 'success', self._tn.before.split('\r\n')[1:]
            return 'success',self._tn.before

    def send(self, command):
        print 'sending command: ', command
        self._tn.sendline(command)


    def stop(self):
        print 'Connection stopped !'
        self._ocd.sendcontrol('c')

    def connect(self):
        #connect to MODIMX27 with JTAG and OpenOCD
        self.is_running = True
        password = 'xxxx'
        myfile = 'openocd.cfg'
        self._ocd = pexpect.spawn('sudo openocd -f %s' % (myfile))
        i = self._ocd.expect(['password', EOF, TIMEOUT])
        if i == 0:
            self._ocd.sendline(password)
            time.sleep(1.0)
            self._connect_to_tn()
        elif i == 1:
            print ' *** OCD Connection failed *** '
            raise Disconnected()
        elif i == 2:
            print ' *** OCD Connection timeout *** '
            raise Timeout()  

    def _connect_to_tn(self):
         #connect to telnet session @ localhost port 4444
         self._tn = pexpect.spawn('telnet %s %s' % (self.HOST, self.port))
         condition = self._tn.expect(['>', EOF, TIMEOUT])
         if condition == 0:
            print 'Telnet opened with success'
         elif condition == 1:
            print self._tn.before
            raise Disconnected()
         elif condition == 2: 
            print self._tn.before
            raise Timeout()

if __name__ =='__main__':
    try:
        tn = ModTelnet()
        tn.connect()   
    except :
            print 'Cannot connect to board!'
            exit(0)
```

The problem is when I'm trying to use send, receive and stop command in ohter modules doing this :

```
    >>> from OCDConnect import *
>>> import time

>>> tn = ModTelnet()
>>> tn.connect()
Telnet opened with success

>>> time.sleep(2.0)
>>> self.send('soft_reset_halt')
MMU: disabled, D-Cache: disabled, I-Cache: disabled

>>> self.stop()
```

It give me an error like : "ModTelnet has no send attribute"
How can I fix this??

Thanks for you help !

Comment: Shouldn't that be `tn.send` and `tn.stop` ?

Comment: Yes it is, sorry, but that's do not working more. How can I make my class ModTelnet in valid python syntaxe?

Comment: Disregard my (deleted) comment about the syntax, please. I was looking at an old python version. Sorry to muddy the waters.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
'send' in dir(tn)
```

if it's False, you haven't implemented the send method.

Comment: oki thank you I will try it tomorrow, I don't have the board with me at home!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the syntax of my class definition :

```
class ModTelnet:
```

And not :

```
class ModTelnet():
```

wich is a useless because I don't inherit from an other class ... :D

Thanks anyway !